# apt-get update error: 500 no space left on device

Tags: apt, raspbian-stretch

Fresh install of NOOBS 2_4_3 Stretch using http://goddess-gate.com for repository mirror. Here is what I'm getting:

```
    sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  chromium-browser libbluray1 lxpanel lxpanel-data pi-bluetooth python3-jedi 
rc-gui
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 59.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 30.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf chromium-
browser armhf 60.0.3112.89-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1010
  500  No space left on device [IP: 93.93.128.211 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --
fix-missing?
...
```

`df -h` gives:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        13G  4.1G  8.1G  34% /
devtmpfs        426M     0  426M   0% /dev
tmpfs           430M     0  430M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           430M   12M  419M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           430M     0  430M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6   68M   21M   47M  31% /boot
tmpfs            86M     0   86M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p5   30M  398K   28M   2% /media/pi/SETTINGS
```

`df -ih`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root        845K  139K  706K   17% /
devtmpfs         107K   369  107K    1% /dev
tmpfs            108K     1  108K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            108K   446  108K    1% /run
tmpfs            108K     3  108K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            108K    10  108K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6      0     0     0     - /boot
tmpfs            108K    17  108K    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p5   8.0K    14  8.0K    1% /media/pi/SETTINGS
```

...
sources.list

```
 cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# *********************************************************************
# ****                       original                             *****
# *********************************************************************
# deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-
free rpi
# *********************************************************************
# *********************************************************************
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free 
rpi
#deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian 
stretch main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://raspbian.ufms.br/raspbian stretch main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://goddess-gate.com/archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch main 
contrib non-free rpi
```

This is the third mirror that I'm seeing this on. I started with the default mirror director. It gave me the 500 error. After a day of searching the web, I decided to try a different mirror and managed to update and install an app. I've tried going back to Noobs 2_4_2 Jessie, but the problem followed. I've tried switching micro-SD cards with no luck. My question is multi-part. What does that error *really* mean? If it is my problem how do I fix it? Does any one have a non-mirror-director mirror that they can verify is not returning this error?

Comment: Have you tried the sugested solution: sudo apt-get --
fix-missing

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Joel-Brooks what is the output of `df -ih` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to drill down into this problem to see where exactly the problem is. I found it. Good news for almost the rest of the community; ***this isn't a Raspberry Pi problem***. Bad news is that for me at least, it is a [Sophos](https://community.sophos.com/products/unified-threat-management/f/general-discussion/16582/no-space-left-on-device-message) problem. Sophos is an enterprise level firewall/web filtering piece of... hardware. 
The way that I determined the root of this problem was to first try to browse through a repository with chromium. I got to the point of opening the Package list when Sophos presented an error of "No space left on device" I then tried to

`wget http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/raspbian/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/debian-installer/binary-armhf/Packages`

the package list and got the 500 alarm with the same error. 
I think that I might be able to do a `apt-get --just-print upgrade' as suggested on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchang site [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19470/list-available-updates-but-do-not-install-them) Sophos is beyond my control and beyond the scope of this site. I'll have IT fix it.

Thanks to all that took time to assist.

Comment: I never thought we'd have to ask a Raspberry Pi user to disable their Anti-Virus while troubleshooting!  :P

Comment: Lol true @Hydraxan14

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Thanks @Ingo. I thought that I had.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. I just ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and that seems to have fixed my error.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it didn't work for me. I got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the sophos antivirus. This is happening because of the way the OS is configured which doesn't allow it to expand root_fs directory.

Here's what you need to do.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

This will open up a pop-up window in the terminal.

Go to Advance
[image]

Select Expand filesystem.
[image]

Reboot the device.

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` should start working. :)

Answer (score -3):

A simple `reboot` solved the problem for myself